# C# Entity Framework - Creating New Claim in database for an already existing user

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, identityserver4

I am trying to add a claim to an already existing user and I have the following code:

```
  userDb = //Gets all the logic for the user.

Task<IdentityResult> userCreate = userManager.CreateAsync(userDb);
```

But when I run the `CreateAsync` it generates a new `UserId` and create a new register in the claims with another Id, which is something that I don't want.
How can I make it to insert a new record passing in the `C#` the `UserId` that I want the line to be?

I think this is all the code that you guys need to get my problem.

Comment: We'd need a little of the schema, but assuming your schema is logical: and the User has a FK to a list of claims: You should get the User and add claims to the claims table with the reference to the parent User.

Comment: You're not making yourself clear. You're trying to add a claim to an existing user? But the code you've mentioned do nothing but creating a user.

Comment: Without anything more to go on; Create implies it creates a record. I'd expect some form of "Add or Update" logic

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a `Claim` for an existing user.

You need to get the specified user, then add claim to it using `UserManager`.

```
userDb = //Gets all the logic for the user.
var roleClaim = new Claim("role", "Admin");
await userManager.AddClaimAsync(userDb, roleClaim);
```